# Check whether Excel file is Password protected

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open an Excel (xlsm) file via VBA. It may or may not be protected with a (known) password. I am using this code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Workbooks.Open filename, Password:=user_entered_pw
opened = (Err.Number=0)
On Error Goto 0
```

Now, this works fine if the workbook has a password. But if it is unprotected, it can NOT be opened. Apparently this is a bug in XL2007 if there is also workbook structure protection active. (http://vbaadventures.blogspot.com/2009/01/possible-error-in-excel-2007.html). On old XL2003, supplying a password would open both unprotected and password protected file.

I tried:

```
Workbooks.Open filename, Password:=user_entered_pw
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then workbooks.open filename
```

This works for unprotected and protected file. However if the user enters a wrong password it runs into the second line and pops up the "enter password" prompt, which I do not want.

How to get around this?

Comment: Have you checked `Err.Number`? Do you maybe get different results if password is wrong / file is not protected?

Comment: I checked, Excel always gives Error 1004 (application specific error). Unfortunately even the error description is identical.

Answer (score 1):

For the record - the reason was indeed the structure protection of the workbook I was opening.
I could circumvent the problem by disabling structure protection, and re-protecting in Workbook_Open() (in the protected workbook).

With structure protection inactive, `Workbooks.Open` with password does not fail even when there is no password.

Since I am opening via a VBA method, the VBA code is already trusted, meaning the Workbook_Open method will surely be called.

Comment: +1 for posting your own findings, which also makes the question worthwhile

Answer (score 0):

1. Use 1004 error handling exclusively for this particular problem, and On Error Resume Next for everything else in the Sub.
2. Above the statement `Workbooks.Open filename, Password:=user_entered_pw` 
   also add another line statement without a password argument.
3. If those (or their combination) don't work, try scouring the .xlsm flat code in Notepad for any hint that a PW protected file differs at that level from one without.  Use that info in a pre-opening function.

Comment: ad 2.: when doing that, the "enter password" prompt will pop up if the file is password protected.
ad 3.: If no protection at all is active, one can recognize the ZIP header (file starts with "PK"). If any protection is present (VBA project, workbook, worksheet, open password), the file is apparently encrypted. So one cannot distuingish a file with open password from one with workbook protection (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I don't know how far you want to go with this, but may I recommend James L. Conger's "Windows API Bible," Charles Petzold's "Programming Windows" and Dan Appleman's "Visual Basic Programmer's Guide to the WIN32 API." You can recognize/stop/intercept/react to the enter password prompt in its tracks before it's ever displayed (and a lot of other things).